# Why does the `.show` property on an object screw up the databinding based on that object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, show

Very Novice question here:

I am writing a snippet which can show and hide a menu if a button is clicked.  The data-binding to the `menuState`variable is not working in the following code, where I have a `.show` property tagged on to the menu state.

```
<html ng-app>
<body>
<div ng-controller="DeathrayController">
    <p>menuState: {{menuState.show}}</p>
    <button ng-click="toggleMenu()">Toggle Menu</button>
    <ul ng-show='menuState.show'>
        <li >Stun</li>
        <li >Disintegrate</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>


function DeathrayController($scope){
    $scope.menuState.show = false;
    $scope.toggleMenu = function(){
        $scope.menuState.show = !$scope.menuState.show;
    };
}

</script>
```

However, this snippet, without the `.show` property on the menuState variable works just fine:

```
<html ng-app>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="DeathrayController">
        <p>menuState: {{menuState}}</p>
        <button ng-click="toggleMenu()">Toggle Menu</button>
        <ul ng-show='menuState'>
            <li >Stun</li>
            <li >Disintegrate</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    function DeathrayController($scope){
        $scope.menuState = false;

        $scope.toggleMenu = function(){
            $scope.menuState = !$scope.menuState;
        };
    }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Why does the `.show` property screw up the databinding?

UPDATE:
This is the error message I get from the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'show' of undefined
    at new DeathrayController (file:///var/folders/61/3h5pq5d14sx9ry5mdgxt00480000gn/T/tmpyxin9v.htm:18:25)
    at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js:27:325)
    at Object.instantiate (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js:27:455)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js:50:239
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js:42:154
    at m (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js:6:312)
    at k (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js:42:16)
    at e (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js:38:198)
    at e (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js:38:215)
    at e (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js:38:215)
```

But then why is `menuState` defined without the `show` property?

Comment: any errors from console? probably something like: "cannot set property 'show' of undefined" ?

Comment: it does say that, but I define it, don't I?

Comment: one minute, working on answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can't declare an object like that:

```
$scope.menuState.show = false;
```

because `$scope.menuState` wasn't defined before, javascript trying to access to property `show` of `$scope.menuState` and throws an error, you need to change your code to:

`$scope.menuState = {show : false}`;